# How to insert existing Form class from WinForms application into the WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have created a Form called: `Form1` in the application called `AMC_Demo`. How to import  `Form1` from WinForms application to the WPF application, step by step?

In the source directory of `AMC_Demo`I have `Form1.cs`, `Form1.Designer.cs` `Form1.resx`. Which and how should I copy to the WPF project directory and how to import them so I can modify and develop it in the WPF solution.

I have already added references to the: `System.Windows.Forms` and `WindowsFormsIntegration`

**How to exacly import the form object to the WPF project?**  I do ask because I have tried copying to WPF project directory then add existing items but it was added to the project as: "other solutions" as far as I remember.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just create the form, and show it, from within the WPF application:

```
// Within some method where you want the form to display
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Show();
```

`WindowsFormsHost` is only required if you want to embed a Windows Forms `UserControl` (or other `Control`) within a WPF `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: Thanks but I would like copy the Form1 from this `AMC_Demo` project. I would not like to create it from scratch.

Comment: @Yoda Just add a reference to this project from the WPF one, and use the existing form.  No need to create it from scratch.

Comment: Is there possibility to add physically the form from `AMC_DEMO` so it will appear in the `WPF` app solution explorer?

Comment: @Yoda Yes - just copy the files, and add them to the other project, if you want to do that.  You'll need to add the references to `System.Windows.Forms`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) walkthrough you see that WinFormHost is a special instance of the WinForm Form class. You can programatically add your controls to it.

For existing Form classes: import the form object into your project (as in, make sure you can edit it), then change it's inheritance from "Form" to "WinFormHost". You can now instantiate it and add it to your WPF Window like you would with a WinFormHost.

**EDIT:** As said in my comment: You copy the files into the WPF Project folder, then in VS right-click the project and select "Add Existing Items". Then select the files you copied. You'll probably need to add some references to WinForm-related .Net libraries for it to compile, but the compilation errors should help you there. Don't copy any project files (like .csproj) though. Those will likely show up as "other solutions".

Comment: In option number two how to exacly import the form object to the WPF project. In the source directory of `AMC_Demo`I have `Form1.cs`, `Form1.Designer.cs` `Form1.resx`. Which and how should I copy to the WPF project directory and how to import them so I can modify it in the WPF directory.

Comment: You'd have to copy all three to the WPF Project folder (or a subfolder you made for this purpose) and then select "Add Existing Items" in Visual Studio. If your form references other classes and controls they don't NEED to be copied if you add a reference to the original project. And like Reed Copsey said, you'll probably need to add some references to certain WinForm .Net libraries.